# App runs successfully but does not work in the android emulator

Tags: android-studio

java code

```
package com.example.spinner_0307;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText ed1;
    Button btn1;
    Spinner sp;
    String branch[]={"CSE","ISE","ECE","MECH","CIVIL","COM"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ed1 = findViewById(R.id.ed1);
        sp = findViewById(R.id.sp);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        sp.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);
        ArrayAdapter array_branch = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, branch);
        sp.setAdapter(array_branch);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){
        Toast.makeText(this, "BTech-"+sp.getItemAtPosition(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView){

    }
}
```

xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightred"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Spinner0307"
        android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.122" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter your course"
        android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.093"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.484" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed1"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.487"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.339" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="227dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:text="Enter"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.792" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.565" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is the code i dont know why it isn't working and it doesn't show any error althought when i run it it says it is installed successfully but after running it on the android studio AVD emulator I see nothing but the home screen and i have tried searchhing for the answer but none of them work

Comment: I'd recommend checking out logcat

Comment: `private static final String[] branch =` would seem better.